# How to give each title for each pin annotations using soap service in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone

How to give each title for each pin annotation using soap service in a `mapview` using `didselectpinannotation` method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own annotation to set a title.

Take a look at : http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/